# Laravel: adding a class to global.php

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to register some event listeners in my laravel project. To do so I added the following to the bottom of my `start\global.php` file:

```
use UserLog;
$userLog = new UserLog;

Event::listen('sentinel.user.login', function (){
    $logData = array('eventDescription' => "User login.");
    $userLog->submitLog($logData);
});
```

When I perform an action that fires that event I get the error message `he use statement with non-compound name 'UserLog' has no effect`

The `use UserLog` should be pulling in the class `models\UserLog.php`. It works in my other files but not in global.php. I figured it was because the classes had not been autoloaded yet, but the code runs after the `ClassLoader` runs.

Is it not possible to add a class to `global.php`? Is there a better place that I should register the events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use it like ([Discussed](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46755)):

```
use \UserLog;
```

> Note that for namespaced names (fully qualified namespace names
>   containing namespace separator, such as Foo\Bar as opposed to global
>   names that do not, such as FooBar), the leading backslash is
>   unnecessary and not allowed, as import names must be fully qualified,
>   and are not processed relative to the current namespace.